# React Native - show ViewController by AppDelegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

AppDelegate.m
This works correct (show splash when app goes into the background)

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NativeScreens" bundle:nil];
  SplashVC *SplashViewController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplashVC"];
  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:SplashViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

But now I need to call this from the react-native.
I created a method with the same functionality:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(showCustomNativeSplashScreen)
{
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NativeScreens" bundle:nil];
  SplashVC *SplashViewController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplashVC"];
  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:SplashViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

It is available in RN, (Im see it from console.log) but when I call it - nothing happens.

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
...
console.log(NativeModules.AppDelegate); // Object{showCustomNativeSplashScreen: function}
NativeModules.AppDelegate.showCustomNativeSplashScreen(); // nothing :(
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to find the upper controller [source](https://gist.github.com/snikch/3661188)

```
- (UIViewController *)topViewController{
  return [self topViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController *)topViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
  if (rootViewController.presentedViewController == nil) {
    return rootViewController;
  }

  if ([rootViewController.presentedViewController isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
    UIViewController *lastViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];
    return [self topViewController:lastViewController];
  }

  UIViewController *presentedViewController = (UIViewController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
  return [self topViewController:presentedViewController];
}

 RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(showCustomNativeSplashScreen)
 {
   self.lastTopVC = [self topViewController];
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NativeScreens" bundle:nil];
   SplashVC *SplashViewController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplashVC"];
   [self.lastTopVC presentViewController:SplashViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
 }
```